# How to create button react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, null, frontend

I created simple React app and need to add Button Component. Unfortunately my code is not working. How I can fix it? Button realisation (React):

```
import React from 'react';

const Button = (props) => {
    return <button className="button">
        {props.children}
    </button>;
}

export { Button };
```

Test code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

import Button from './Button';

describe('Button', () => {
    /**

     * children - button text

     */

    it('Button with text', () => {
        const component = shallow(<Button>Button</Button>);

        expect(component.html()).toEqual('<button class="button">Button</button>');
    });
});
```

[files in dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6Aog.png)

Error in test:

```
 Expected: "<button class=\"button\">Button</button>"
 Received: null
```

Comment: you mean test not working or code

Comment: My code on test request answers with null instead of just something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This import line:

```
import Button from './Button';
```

is asking the build to get the *default* export from the module, but you're exporting that component inside an object.

So either:

```
export default Button;
```

Or:

```
import { Button } from './Button';
```

(I'd also suggest adding parentheses around your JSX in your return, and importing some CSS specific to that component.)

```
function Button(props) {
  return (
    <button className="button">
      {props.children}
    </button>;
  );
}

export default Button;
```

Comment: Thanks that's working

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this,

```
it('Button with text', () => {
        const component = shallow(<Button>Button</Button>);

        expect(component.html()).toEqual('<button class=\"button\">Button</button>');
    });
```

Comment: Same result, Received: null